# ligth desktop on ubuntu server v16.04

Tags: server

How prevent LXDE to start at boot.

I prefer to start ubuntu server 16.04 without LXDE running so it coms with the command prompt afther boot.
Start LXDE with the command startx.
So how can i prevent that LXDE is started at boot time.

Tanks,
Ian

Comment: Does LXDE use lightdm?

Comment: do you want to install a fresh Ubuntu or modify an already installed one?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could see with a quick look at apt, lxde should be using lxdm instead of lightdm. If this is the case - AND lxdm is started through the systemd service "lxdm", the following command will disable it during startup:

```
systemctl disable lxdm.service
```

In case I am wrong with all these assumptions (I don't use lxde, so I pretty well might be), try to disable the lightdm service, which might in this case be a wrapper that starts whatever is configured somewhere else:

```
systemctl disable lightdm.service
```

does this solve your issue?

Comment: LXDE on werver 16.04 is not working properly , problem is in LXDE itself.